# $3^n - 2^m = \pm 41$ is not possible. How to prove it?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

$3^n - 2^m = \pm 41$ is not possible for integers $n$ and $m$. How to prove it?

Comment: How many congruences have you tried? How about mod 9?

Comment: The equation $3^n-2^m=\pm1$ in integers was fully solved by Levi ben Gerson ($\approx1320$). What's the trouble to do this one yourself by considering modulo 4 and 3 (or 9)? It looks a homework problem if you don't state your reasons and don't indicate your approaches.

Comment: Modulo 8 and modulo 9 suffice.

Comment: Wadim: if n is positive even, and m is congruent to 2 mod 6 (but not equal to 2), then 3^n - 2^m is congruent to +41 mod 8 and mod 9.  So I don't see how "modulo 8 and modulo 9 suffice".

Comment: A good point, Michael! But I have to go to bed and think of a fix later. Serena just won 1/4 (and Venus lost earlier).

Comment: If m and n are even ... well, any mathematician would know what to do next. 

Comment: If n and m are both even, then 41 is a difference of two squares, which factorises.

Comment: What can be said about the integers with a representation of the form 3^n−2^m or 2^n−3^m?

Comment: Follow something like http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/70360.html

Answer (score 23):

The congruence $3^n - 2^m \equiv 41\pmod{60}$ has no solutions.

The congruence $3^n - 2^m \equiv -41\pmod{72}$ has no solutions.

Comment: Very nice! Is there an integer $t$ such that $3^n-2^m=t$  has no solutions in non-negative integers $m,n$ but for which this cannot be proved by reducing the equation modulo $N$ as above for any $N$? I suspect so (number theory is too hard for this sort of technique to be that powerful) but it would be nice to know an explicit example!

Comment: I have a different opinion about the existence of such $t$ - I think it does not exist. But I would also very welcome to see a counterexample if it exists.

Comment: Kevin's question intrigued me.  So I wondered if these moduli were special somehow.  It turns out that $3^n-2^m\equiv 41$ fails modulo 601 (and then again at 6553) and $3^n-2^m\equiv -41$ fails modulo 1321.  All of these moduli are primes (as that is what I restricted my search to).

It seems that if we find a prime for which both 2 and 3 have relatively small orders, the chance that we hit $t$ gets small.

Comment: I tried a bunch of small moduli but was doing the work in my head, and didn't make it to 60 or 72.

Comment: @Michael, you've done it modulo 72 yesterday! See your comment to mine above. Because $72=8\cdot 9$ (I believe). Modulo 60 is much less trivial, Max's answer is really nice. (In dreams I started to think of applying linear forms in logs. :-) )

Comment: @Kevin: I suggest that you turn your interrogative comment into a new question.  It will get a lot more attention that way, and rightfully so, I think.  

Comment: @Pete: done: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30031/proving-non-existence-of-solutions-to-3n-2mt-without-using-congruences

Answer (score 15):

As a valuable hint for solving the problem, I consider the following extract from my lectures on elementary number theory.

**Theorem** ($\approx1320$; Levi ben Gerson 1288--1344).
The equations
$$
(1) \quad 3^p-2^q=1
$$
and
$$
(2) \quad 2^p-3^q=1
$$
have no solutions in integers $p,q>1$, except the solution
$p=2$, $q=3$ to equation (1).

*Proof.*
(1) If $p=2k+1$, then
$$
2^q=3^p-1=3\cdot9^k-1\equiv2\pmod4,
$$
which is impossible for $q>1$.

If $p=2k$, then $2^q=3^p-1=(3^k-1)(3^k+1)$ implying
$3^k-1=2^u$ and $3^k+1=2^v$. Since
$2^v-2^u=(3^k+1)-(3^k-1)=2$, we have $v=2$ and $u=1$.
This corresponds to the unique solution
$q=u+v=3$ and $p=2$.

(2) If $q\ge1$, then $3^q+1$ is not divisible by~$8$.
Indeed, if $q=2k$, then $3^q+1=9^k+1\equiv2\pmod8$;
and if $q=2k+1$, then $3^q+1=3\cdot9^k+1\equiv4\pmod8$.
Therefore $p\le2$, hence $p=2$. The latter implies $q=1$
which does not correspond to a solution.