# Lower bound on # of nonzero digits in ternary expansions of powers of 2?

Tags: nt.number-theory, digits

Does anyone know of any lower bounds on the number of nonzero digits that appear in powers of 2 when written to base 3?  (Other than the easy "If it's more than 8 it has to have at least 3.")  I know there's been some stuff done with powers of 2 written to base 3, but I can't seem to find anything that quite answers this question.

(Are there more general such bounds? Powers of a written to base b? (To avoid triviality, suppose that no power of a is a power of b... or are stricter conditions needed?) From what I can tell, it looks like even specific instances of these are hard, so I suppose I should stick to the specific version.)

Comment: This should be a pretty open problem. I can't find a related problem of can the square be written by two digits only.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512006

Comment: @Junkie: Yes, I saw that.  It didn't appear to address what I'm asking, though, or at least not that I noticed.... did I miss something?

Comment: "Rather than easy" (at least three nonzero digits) is Levi ben Gerson's http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29926/3n-2m-pm-41-is-not-possible-how-to-prove-it/29928#29928. The problem has to do something with simultaneous (special) rational approximations to $\log 2$ and $\log 3$.

Comment: So, the insolvability of $a^m-b^n=1$ for $a,b,n,n\ge2$ (Catalan's equation), except $3^2-2^3=1$, implies "at least 3 nonzero digits" for any $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This paper of D. J. Newman (On the number of binary digits in a multiple of three. Proc Amer Math Soc. 21(1969): 719--721) proves upper and lower bounds on the number of binary 1-digits in multiples of 3 (most of them have substantively more 1's than 0's).

Comment: I don't have UPINT (Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory) handy, it's worth having a look to see what's in there. 

Comment: @Gerry: Yeah, I couldn't find it in there either - some similar things, but not this.  E.g. it mentions a conjecture that every sufficiently large power of 2 has a zero when written in base 3, but that's more or less the opposite of what I'm looking for!  I was kind of hoping its non-appearance in there meant it wasn't an unsolved problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A nontrivial lower bound can be found in a paper of Cam Stewart (see http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/PM_Dept/Homepages/Stewart/Jour_Books/J-reine-ange-Math-1980.pdf). He proves, more generally, for fixed bases a and b for which $\log a/\log b$ is irrational, that the sum of the number of nonzero digits in the base a and base b digits of an integer n exceeds (essentially) $$\log \log n/ \log \log \log n.$$

Comment: Ooh, thank you! Making use of this might not be easy, but it certainly does answer the question, and in generality, too!